# creating random monster encounters for 2d rpg. im using visual basics 2010

Tags: software-engineering

i just started programming a couple days ago. ive picked up on it pretty easy enough, but i still have a lot to learn. i was wondering if someone could help me out with making a system for random enemy encounters. with how many monsters appear and their stats.drop rates,enemy commands, etc. i have a program with a char on a bitmap to test things on, so if anyone could help me, it would be greatly appreciated. thanks!

Comment: First off, we're going to need more information. What sort of game? What does the enemy class look like? When should it be generated? What should be generated? **What have you tried and what is your exact question?**

Comment: just a basic 2d rpg like old ff games. and i was thinking about just starting off with just using a simple goblin. i guess my question would be how to make goblins appear in random encounters on a world map or dungeon. and how to make it random so its not a battle every 10 steps.

Comment: For starters, http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Random_Encounter describes how Final Fantasy I's random encounter system worked. But your question is quite general, and you need to rephrase it - pick one of the things you mentioned and describe in more detail, perhaps?

Comment: I suggest researching other rpg games, until you actually know what you want to do, instead of a vague sense of what you think might want to do.

Comment: ok well do you know of a good tutorial or guide for vb on creating a simple 2d rpg? ive been looking and cant find a good one. cuz that would be a lot easier than asking A LOT of questions on a forum like this. any suggestions or advice would be helpful and appreciated.

Comment: i mean, ive been playing rpgs for about 13-14 years. so i have a pretty good idea of what my final project will be but im just trying to learn one thing at a time. so i dont get confused or frustrated.

Comment: Is this a design or programming question?

Comment: programming question. sorry i didnt mention that in the title.

Answer (score 2):

That is the art of programming, figure what you want and make a program that does it. You haven't yet figured what you want. You have an idea on the level of: "Sorta like Diablo", but you are not able to describe in sufficient detail what that actually means, and thus you can't convert it to code.

I think you should skip the random part for now, it's a whole host of problems and tricky decisions that you shouldn't worry about now. For someone a few days green an RPG is plenty overambitious on it's own.

What projects have you by the way done so far?

Comment: well ive made a calculator,web browser, some easy stuff. um a bitmap editor/creator. and basically a started rpg. but its just a char moving around on a grass bitmap with trees and mountains.

Comment: So the RPG is your first game project. Then I'll be so bold as to suggest that you do some other games first. Make a Tetris clone, it's most certainly an unoriginal suggestion, but it has good learning value and you shouldn't have as grave problems figuring what you want in a Tetris clone.

Comment: ok. i was gunna make a few games first before i really got into the rpg. like pong, tetris, etc.

Comment: Then make those games and worry about your RPG when you are ready.

Comment: ok just made pong and tic tac toe so ima make tetris now. lol how would i know if i would be ready to make an rpg?

Comment: It's hard to say. You do though seem awfully productive, that is a lot of programs in a short time. If you want to know where you are I think you should show off what you have made, your code and your games.

Answer (score 1):

If you're thinking of developing something along the lines of a Roguelike, try [this](http://roguebasin.roguelikedevelopment.org/mediawiki/index.php/Roguelike_Dev_FAQ) FAQ. While that wiki doesn't generally tell you how to program any of the things it describes it does give you a good look at what you need to consider while designing an rpg.

Comment: ok thank you very much. this should be very helpful. i appreciate it.